# Button enable / disable rules

Tags: android

What should I learn so button would get disabled or enabled automatically by some rules?

Example If there is no necessary text, disable button. If there is necessary text but other things is not set up correctly, keep disabling button. I imagine there could be something like button listener that is waiting for all set rules to be true.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to make a `custom button` which is `subclass` from `Button`. Something like:

```
class AutoDisableButton extends Button{
     //some constructors...
     @override
     void setText(String abc){
          super.setText(abc);
         setEnable("disable".equal(abc) ? false : true)
     }
}
```